# Cancel confirmation email in Virtuemart 2

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

Do you know if is there any way to avoid/cancel the confirmation email that receives the client after a purchase in Virtuemart? 
I would like to keep the admin email.

I searched for that option in the Virtuemart control panel without any result.

I have Virtuemart 2.0.20b and Joomla 2.5.11

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cancel the confirmation email I made the following:

In the file components/com_virtuemart/helpers/shopfunctionsf.php I changed this (line 243):

```
$user= self::sendVmMail($view, $recipient,$noVendorMail);
```

for this:

```
if ($viewName=='invoice' AND in_array($vars['orderDetails']['details']['BT']->order_status, array('P','U')))
    $user = null;
else
    $user= self::sendVmMail($view, $recipient,$noVendorMail);
```

There is a more complete answer in [this url](http://www.chillcreations.com/en/manuals/ccvaom/548-how-to-disable-default-virtuemart-e-mails)